# How do I get the only achievement in The Stanley Parable Demo, "You Won!"?

Tags: achievements, the-stanley-parable

The new [Stanley Parable HD remake demo](http://store.steampowered.com/app/247750/) has one single achievement, entitled "You Won!"

How do I get it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You actually get the achievement, but the game then takes it away a moment later. To keep it, as soon as you get the achievement hit shift+tab to go to the Steam overlay. Then bring up the task manager and 'end task' the demo. Now you can't play the demo ever again, but it will show up in you game library with the achievement and count as a 100% completed game.

Comment: "Now you can't play the demo ever again" is an odd side effect. Any idea why?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I imagine you can play the demo, but will lose the achievement when you play through that part again.

Comment: @kotekzot Oooohhh. Ambiguous semantics, solved!

Answer (score 3):

There is a point in the demo where you are instructed to do the classic Half-Life 2 physics demonstration:

> Put a cup into a garbage bin.

When you do that, you get the **Video Games!!** achievement (subtitled **You WON!!!**)…

Or at least, that's what the demo tells you. In reality, you don't get the achievement. You will have to make of that what you will, as with the rest of the parable.

Here you can see that the achievement is showing up in the Steam overlay with 100% achievements earned, but when you click "View All Achievements" and see it in the browser, it's showing "0/1 (0%)".

[image: Carefully-annotated Steam overlay showing both 100% and 0% achievements.]<sup>*[Click to embiggen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSeJS.png)*</sup>

Comment: Er, but I did that and I didn't get the achievement.  Unless he only added the achievement today?

Comment: @BlueRaja It's possible. There's narration about giving the player an achievement. If that voiceover wasn't in the demo before, it's probably been updated, yeah.

Comment: Aha. Seems there's a… bug? Yet another metagame screwing-with-the-player-feature? The achievement is "given", but never actually shows up as unlocked.

Comment: Oh yeah, I remember that part.  I remember the achievement popup showing in the upper-left though (Steam always shows them in the lower right), meaning it wasn't a real achievement popup, it was faked within the game.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: Games *can* request the overlay pop-ups to appear in a different corner; it just *defaults* to the lower right. Whether or not this game does that, I don't know, but seeing it in the top-left corner doesn't mean it's faked.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen: That's, uh, not true.  [Here](https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/ugs) are the API docs for steamworks achievements *(you may need to sign into your steam account and accept a steamworks agreement to view it)*.  There is no way for a developer to indicate where they want to popup to show up.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: It's a [game overlay](https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/game_overlay) setting, not an achievement setting. Borderlands 2 and Age of Empires II are good examples of games that use this, but they're not the only ones.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen +1 thanks for sharing that

Answer (score -2):

To get the achievement you have to actually put the cup on the top of the rafters instead of the garbage  can.

Comment: There are no rafters.  I just tried putting it on top of the boxes, but now I can't reach the cup.  Eventually the announcer just gives you the achievement to keep the demo going, but it works exactly the same as if you had put the cup in the bin.

Comment: There are planks of wood going across the top of the room. Seriously, that is how you get the achievement. If you doubt me, go do it yourself.

Comment: Alright, I just tried that.  It does the same thing as usual, giving you the achievement and taking it away.  However, I'll remove my downvote since it does give slightly different dialog.